# onsenuiのtheme切り替えがうまくいかない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

お世話になります。
monacaクラウドでonsenuiのcssを変更すると画面が真っ白になってしまいました。
回復手段・確認すべき場所はどのようなものがありますか？

行った手順

1. Monacaクラウドでプロジェクトを開く
2. 「ファイル」-「JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除」を選択
3. OnsenUI（Monaca Version）Ver=1.3.11の設定ボタンをクリック
4. 「blue-basic-theme.css」のチェックを外し、「blue-theme.css」のチェックを入れてOKを押す。

以上です。

Comment: Monacaデバッガー上の現象ですか？同期データを削除して再度実行しても変わりませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Monacaクラウドのプレビュー画面とMonacaデバッガー両方で発生しました。教示いただいた同期データの削除も今試しましたが、状況変わりません。

Comment: `JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除`から`Onsen UI`を一度削除して追加してもダメですか？

Comment: 一度削除して、OnsenUI（MonacaVersion）を追加しましたが、状況変わりません。

Comment: 時間がないので、プロジェクトを新規作成してテーマ設定してからコードをコピペすると動きました。。oTakさん、時間を割いていただき本当にありがとうございました。